# How can run java GUI in browser by GWT

Tags: java, swing, gwt, web-applications

I want to run java swing application on web browser over GWT (Google Web Toolkit
) or another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely clear what you want to do.

GWT is compiling Java source code to JavaScript. That JavaScript is executed on the browser. There is no direct connection between Java Swing code and the JavaScript executed in the browser, especially, Swing is not supported by the GWT widget library and cannot be compiled to JavaScript. You can find the supported packages and classes here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

If you try to execute a Java Swing desktop application from the browser environment, that would only work out using WebStart, where the browser forwards control to the WebStart application using the "jnlp:" protocol handler, installed with the Java Plugin. More information can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html

If the Swing application you are talking about is an Applet, you can output the required embedding code for the applet into the HTML output of your GWT application's view. Either static or by dynamically adding a HTML panel with the respective contents. The applet support is fading away in browsers, but you can find samples here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

Choose your weapon.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you use Eclipse as the IDE here. I would suggest trying this:

> Run mvn gwt:debug
>   Connect to it as a remote Java appl. from Eclipse

Make sure you have all the related classpath specs and an appropriate Run Configuration. Try from your browser using the localhost URL and correct port.

You can also go through this page for Google Developers.
https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0

Comment: *"Chocks
LinkedIn: https://uk.linkedin.com/.."* Do not put this information into the end of posts. It belongs in [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5836867/chockalingam-subramanian).

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question (agreed, the question is not in best shape...)